# Create .rpm package for java - any automatic software?

Tags: java, rpm, rpmbuild

I want to create an RPM package for a java application. I have never done rpm packages and i still do not quite understand how to do it manually. Is there a software that can do this (or at least most of it) automatically ?. Currently if user wants to use application he/she has to download a tar.gz file, un-tar it and then run .sh file that takes care of the installation.

My dev workmachine is Windows ( don't bully me for that ! ) if that helps at all.

I have found [THIS](http://www.icewalkers.com/Linux/Software/57020/Alien.html) Software but i am not sure if its applicable to what i want to do. Please note that current project set up - is NON Maven

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [insall4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) for this job. There is a ant task for creating installer (and launcher)

Comment: that is just great ;)

Comment: It fails to handle some options available in a plain spec file, it's the same with Debian, it doesn't support multi-architecture packages. I advise you to use Red Line RPM (with Ant or Maven) instead of install4j if you look specifically for a reliable solution to create RPM under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Some days ago, I found several softwares doing that on Sourceforge.net but one of them was just a graphical interface above RPM build tools, I needed to understand what to put into a spec file and in .rpmmacros... [The other one](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpmbuilder/) seems too simple to do what I want. Currently, I'm trying to use Redline RPM pure Java library, you can use it with or without Ant if you want. I'm still trying to make it work as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22770027/how-to-create-a-rpm-package-with-redline-rpm-java-library).