# How to create a RPM package with Redline RPM Java library?

Tags: java, rpm

I would like to create a RPM package for [my Java game](http://tuer.sourceforge.net) (currently packaged as JARs + JNLP file). I use Ant as a build tool. I cannot use platform-dependent tools as the few developers who use my source code use several operating systems, not necessarily GNU Linux unlike me.

At first, I tried to use [JDIC](http://www.javadesktop.org/articles/jdic/index.html) but its source code hasn't been maintained for years and I had to modify tons of things just to make it compile anew. Moreover, it just calls the native RPM tools under the hood. Then, I found [RPM Ant task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/rpm.html%E2%80%8E) but it uses the native RPM tools under the hood too. After that, I found [RPM Maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin) but I don't want to switch to another build tool now just to create a RPM package.

Finally, I found Redline RPM pure Java library which has an Ant task, there is an example [here](http://redline-rpm.org/usage.html). I still don't understand how to use it. I understand the role of a few basic fields (group, version, release, name), I know that I have to use "depends" to indicate that my game requires at least Java 1.7 but I don't know what to do with my JARs, where to put the .desktop file for the desktop shortcut and where to put the bash script that calls the main class to run my game. As a first step, I'd like to create a binary package. I have found another example using this library [here](http://subversion.assembla.com/svn/cfdistro/trunk/cfdistro/src/cfdistro/rpm.xml). Do I have to provide an uninstall script too? Should I use a postinstall script to copy the .desktop file into the desktop directory? Should I use a tarfileset for the third party libraries? I know it would be better to put the JARs into several RPMs but I want to succeed in doing something simple before doing more elaborated but cleaner things.

Comment: You should read the packaging guidelines for your target distribution and follow them. In general you want your binary in /usr/bin, your data wherever you plan on reading it from (the guidelines probably have suggestions and possibly even automatic macros for those paths), same for the desktop file. You shouldn't need a script unless you have to do something to the system (like add a user) that rpm doesn't handle for you (it does handle copying/installing files).

Comment: I have no executable, I need to call "java -jar tuer.jar" to run my game. The class files and the data (images, sounds, ...) are in the JARs. You remind me that Linux distros have slightly different packaging guidelines. Under Mageia, games executables are put into /usr/games. XDG_DESKTOP_DIR isn't set under KDE, I'll have to look at .config/user-dirs.dirs :s

Comment: You mentioned `the bash script that calls the main class to run my game` that's your `executable`. The JARs are your data in this case (though being in java imposes some java path constraints on your if you don't want to manage the path yourself though in this case you probably do). In which case you probably just need to make yourself a `/usr/share/$game` or similar directory, stuff your JARS under there and install the script into `/usr/bin/$game` and be done. (Or whatever system like that fits your target packaging scheme.)

Comment: Thank you. Ok I have to put "tuer" bash script into /usr/bin or /usr/games (depending on the distro) and all JARs into /usr/share/tuer. When you write "be done", does it mean that's it? I don't write to write an uninstall script, do I?

Comment: If all you are doing is installing files using the `%files` section (or java library equivalent) then that's it. RPM handles installing and uninstalling the listed files for you, that's its job. You only need scripts for custom actions that RPM can't handle for you. I would suggest that you might be well served by trying to make the rpm by hand (with a spec file and the `rpmbuild` tools) first to see how they work and how the RPM is created and then porting that to your java library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26194764/458157). I just have to add a short script to run the application.

P.S: By the way, I now use my own tool (which uses Redline RPM under the hood), it's fully documented, free software (under GPL) and works for DEB, APP and EXE (via NSIS) too, it's called [Java Native Deployment Toolkit](https://tuer.sourceforge.io/en/documentation/#jndt).

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a simple tutorial on how to use redline [here](http://ronanquillevere.github.io/2015/06/18/redline-rpm-generation.html#.VfkfpBFVhBc)

Basically everything you have to do build an empty rpm is that :

```
org.redline_rpm.Builder builder = new Builder();

File directory = new File(".");
builder.setType(RpmType.BINARY);
builder.setPlatform(Architecture.X86_64, Os.LINUX);
builder.setPackage("name", "1", "1");
builder.setDescription("Description");
builder.setSummary("Summary");

builder.build(directory);
```

You can add dependency on certain commands : example

```
builder.addDependencyMore("tar", "0");
builder.addDependencyMore("python", "0");
builder.addDependencyMore("wget", "0");
```

Then you can add some pre-install script or post-install script and files too.

```
builder.setPostInstallScript(xxx);

File tarball = new File("/the/dir/of/your/file/file.tar.gz");
builder.addFile("/where/to/put/it/file.tar.gz", tarball);
```

Redline maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.redline-rpm</groupId>
    <artifactId>redline</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Good job, I have mentioned your tutorial in the JogAmp wiki.