# How to make Redline RPM Library work with Ant?

Tags: java, ant, package, redhat, rpm

I use Ant as a build tool, I put this line into my Ant script at the very beginning:

```
<taskdef name="pure-java-rpm" classname="org.redline_rpm.ant.RedlineTask" classpath="lib/ant/redline-1.1.16.jar" />
```

I call it further:

```
<pure-java-rpm group="Games" name="${project-unix-name}" version="0" destination="${destdir}">
        <zipfileset prefix="/usr/share/games/${project-unix-name}" file="${destdir}/${game-jar-filename}"/>
        <depends name="java" version=">= 1.7"/>
    </pure-java-rpm>
```

I get the following error message: 
BUILD FAILED
/home/gouessej/Documents/programmation/java/workspace/tuer/build.xml:445: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/compressors/bzip2/BZip2CompressorInputStream

However, Apache Commons Compress isn't mentioned, it doesn't seem to be a dependency of this library according to [the "usage" page](http://redline-rpm.org/usage.html). Do I really have to add Apache Commons Compress into the classpath of this task definition to make it work? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions don't mention the dependencies, you need at least SLF4J, Bountycastle, XZ and Apache Commons Compress to use Redline RPM. I've just modified my task definition:

```
<taskdef name="pure-java-rpm" classname="org.redline_rpm.ant.RedlineTask">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement path="bcpg-jdk15on-151.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="commons-compress-1.8.1.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="slf4j-simple-1.7.7.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="xz-1.4.jar"/>
        <pathelement path="redline-1.1.16.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

You can find those JARs here:

[Apache Commons Compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/download_compress.cgi)

[Bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html)

[SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/download.html)

[XZ](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/tukaani/xz/1.4/)

Comment: These should be problems of the past :). I suggest you use [maven](https://maven.apache.org/index.html) build tool which has complete dependency management. With ant you can use [Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/)

Comment: At first, Redline RPM can be used with Maven too. Secondly, Maven alone doesn't solve this problem, rpm-maven-plugin requires native RPM support. Building RPMs on platforms with no native support of the RPM build tools isn't a problem of the past. Redline RPM solves it partially. Finally, switching to Maven requires to follow a strict directory layout, it's not trivial and it wouldn't have solved my problem without additional plugins. If some dependencies are missing in the pom file, knowing them is still useful to fix it. Switching to the latest trendy tool doesn't solve everything.